# What is a status-only Git repository?

Tags: git

The [documentation for the `git update-index` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) has this to say about the `--info-only` switch :

> `--info-only` is used to register files without placing them in the object database. This is useful for **status-only repositories**.

Since Git is a content-tracking system as opposed to a file-tracking system, I'm curious about scenarios in which you'd want to do that; that is, register files with the index without actually placing them (and presumably their contents) in the object database.

I've also googled around for the term "status-only repository" without success. Could someone clarify what such a repository is and what it's good for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The change that [added that feature](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df6e151636992edc5824af53b62b451737b0d24d) was part of a series of patches by Bryan Larsen to “support working without the object database”. [This is what he explained it with](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/5818):

> Sometimes you may wish to keep an audit trail of what changed, where, 
>   and by whom. You do not need to know the exact details of the change, 
>   and the files are so large that keeping an extra copy of the data in the 
>   object database cache is prohibitively expensive.
>
> Git is (almost) ideally suited for this. There's very little out there 
>   that is faster than git-diff-cache.
>
> The design of git also facilitates this. git-update-cache --cacheinfo 
>   allows the index to be updated without an object in the database, and 
>   operations can then be performed around the index.  However, there are 
>   some things that are inconvenient and one show stopper.

There wasn’t actually any discussion going on about the *why* on that thread, and I could find another one covering the topic. So it might have been an idea Bryan played around with and wanted to have for himself.

I’m personally not aware of anything that actually *uses* this for something, so this might be a theoretical use case after all. On the other hand, the idea is pretty simple and could actually be used for something.

Comment: Ah didn't think to check the git log of the git ;-) Cheers.